# IdentityServer4 integrate with Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I created an empty Asp.Net core project and added the following lines to play around IdentityServer4.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}

public static class Config
{
    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers() => new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "",
                Username = "User1",
                Password = "password",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("first_name", "first"),
                    new Claim("last_name", "last")
                }
            }
        };

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() => new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() => new List<Client>();
}
```

And it works after I added the Quick Start UI components.

Now I want it to be able the authenticate the user with Active Directory of the company. How to change the code?

Answer (score 2):

Basically AD is an External Authentication provider for Identity Server.

Despite the QuickstartUI components (that you have already added), you need to setup this provider.

2 main steps:

1.In `Startup.cs`, in `ConfigureServices` you need to add the provider (after you have registered IdentitiyServer):

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
{
    iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
    iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});
```

2.In `Program.cs` you need to add IISIntegration:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

Then on your login page, you will be asked to select which authentication provider to use, to login, and you will have the Windows button available. You can read more [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html).

Comment: How about if I want Windows only authentication?

Comment: Well basically the setup I provided is mainly for Windows Authentication. I'm not sure that you need AD hooked up behind it, to work. The link from the documentation is for Windows authentication only, and AD is more like an example for a Windows auth, not a requirement. Have a look http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html

Comment: The (1) part of the code you posted uses `IISOptions`. But the (2) of the answer uses `UseKestrel()`. Should the application use IIS or Kestrel?

Comment: Both. In the second part I also have `UseIISIntegration()`. `When using Kestrel, you must run “behind” IIS and use the IIS integration`

Comment: I added the code. However, the url `https://localhost:44378/Account/Login` doesn't show the option to select which authentication provider to use.

Comment: I guess I will need to modify the login post method in `AccountController.cs`?

Comment: Yes, there were some options there, based on the number of external providers, and if local login is allowed. Have a look there.

Comment: Actually, I don't need the local login. What's the best option?

Comment: Have a look around `BuildLoginViewModelAsync`. It has changed a lot since I cloned the quickstart in my current project, but I see that the method is still there. This is building the view model, based on which some things are shown/hidden from the login page

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-active-directory-ad-as-the-repository-for-authentication-with-identityserver4-fa010e0980db